# Special counter for loop in django

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop

I have a page with objects in django application.
I display it on using a for loop.
I want to do something like that if the loop is at 5 cycle, I want to appear to the new page. I need this to generate the pdf file.

```
{% for skill in person.skills.all %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
        <div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But in documentation I found something like this:

```
forloop.counter
forloop.counter0
forloop.revcounter
forloop.revcounter0
forloop.first
forloop.last
```

forloop.parentloop  For nested loops, this is the loop surrounding the current one

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Selcuk I would like to appear on each page only 5 texts (objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter:

```
{% for skill in person.skills.all %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" %}
        <div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That will add a page break at every row that is divisible by 5 (ie. 5, 10, 15, etc).